# How do I create an optional C++ template parameter for a class?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have a class right now that is defined as

```
template <class A> class MyClass { };
```

I would like to add an optional template parameter B which would lead to

```
template <class A, class B> class MyClass {};
```

but I want it in such a way such that if B is not specified, i.e. if I define

```
MyClass<double> x;
```

then B will be the same type as A (or double in the above case) as well.

Is that even possible in C++?

Answer (score 3):

```
template <class A, class B = A> class MyClass {};
```

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/UOfwunFkwBZH7sLE)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you simply set the default value for B:

```
template <class A, class B = A> class MyClass {};
```